# How to combine these 2 javascript codes in one?

Tags: javascript

```
if (value === "up") {
  for (const key in data) {
    fetchedData.push({
      id: data[key].id,
      name: data[key].name,
      image: data[key].image,
      location: data[key].location,
      price: data[key].price,
    });
  }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (value === "down") {
  for (const key in data) {
    fetchedData.push({
      id: data[key].id,
      name: data[key].name,
      image: data[key].image,
      location: data[key].location,
      price: data[key]["fixed-price"],
    });
  }
}
```

They share also the same things, only the price is different. Ive tried `if (value === "up" ||value === "down")` and then added conditional inside the for in loops but doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get correct property name according to your condition in variable. Then use that variable in `price` property as `price: data[key][propertyName]`.

```
if (value === "up" || value === "down") {
  let propertyName = value === "up" ? "price" : "fixed-price";

  for (const key in data) {
    fetchedData.push({
      id: data[key].id,
      name: data[key].name,
      image: data[key].image,
      location: data[key].location,
      price: data[key][propertyName],
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
        for (const key in data) {
          fetchedData.push({
            id: data[key].id,
            name: data[key].name,
            image: data[key].image,
            location: data[key].location,
            price: value === "up" ? data[key].price || data[key]["fixed-price"],
          });
        }
```

To add more conditionals in price, you could set the price beforehand like this:

```js
let price;
if(value === "up"){
    price = data[key].price
} else if(value === "down") {
    price = data[key]["fixed-price"]
}

for (const key in data) {
   fetchedData.push({
     id: data[key].id,
     name: data[key].name,
     image: data[key].image,
     location: data[key].location,
     price: price,
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a ternary operator:

```js
    if (value === "up" || value === "down") {
      for (const key in data) {
        fetchedData.push({
          id: data[key].id,
          name: data[key].name,
          image: data[key].image,
          location: data[key].location,
          price:  value === "up" ? data[key].price : data[key]["fixed-price"]
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **json object** :

```
const myJSON = '{"up":"price","down":"fixed-price"}';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
if (value === "up" || value === "down") {
  for (const key in data) {
    fetchedData.push({
      id: data[key].id,
      name: data[key].name,
      image: data[key].image,
      location: data[key].location,
      price: data[key][myObj[value]],
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i have learned a lot from all of you!